# Outlook mail filtering based on sequence of emails

Tags: email, filter, outlook, rule

I receive dozens or hundreds of emails from nagios each day.  Many are related to the same service/server.  For example, I get two emails within a few minutes of each other:

1. State CRITICAL on server: service
2. State OK on server: service

Outlook doesn't see this as a conversation so I can treat them that way.

I would like to have a filter, rule or process that would see "State OK" then go find all other emails that came in before that associated with that server: service and delete them.

I started with rules that took all emails associated with a server/service that are not OK and put them in a folder.  My hope was to then have a rule that would see the OK email and delete all the messages in that folder then delete the OK message.

Unfortunately, I was not able to see an action to delete all emails in a folder.

I'm stuck at this point.  I thought about writing a vba add-in, but it looks like the admin has that turned off.

Any suggestions?  This could be useful for many system admins.

Answer (score 0):

There are two macros you can include in the automatic email that Nagios sends out.

$SERVICEPROBLEMID$
$LASTSERVICEPROBLEMID$

You can append the serviceproblemid macro to the subject of the email on a critical/warning/unknown state and append the lastserviceproblemid macro to the recovery alert.

That way you can tie the two emails together and outlook can process accordingly (might take some playing with Outlook rules but I'm sure it can be done.)